# Quickest way to convert xml schema to objects in Action Script at runtime

Tags: java, xml, actionscript-3, jaxb

I have an XML Schema, and I would like to have action script classes out of it. The schema is really big. I have converted it by jaxb to java classes, but it's really a huge task to convert all the files manually to work with. is there a faster way for doing that ?

Comment: I've never heard of such a tool but writing your own won't be that hard. You can even use Adobe AIR for such task, as it can work with files and you can use the Actionscript Workers for the long operations. You just need to create an Actionscript file for every node in an XML.

Comment: should I depend on the java generated files ?
how can I let Adobe AIR do such task? I'm newbie in actionscript...

Comment: If you're more comfortable writing in Java. Write a program in Java which will load the XML and create files for AS classes and write stuff in them.